# Multiple Pie chart using DC js and Crossfilter along with Datatables

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to create something like this
[image]

I achieve this using simple D3 but I want to make it interactive and filter data via the selection by using dc.js (pie chart, DataTables) and crossfilter.

I don't understand how to provide multiple groups and dimensions to dc.js pie charts from the below array:

```
var data = [
        {Batch: 4563, Contact: "MFG-MQA", lateSteps: 668, completedSteps: 2263, openSteps: 4144},
        {Batch: 6234, Contact: "MFG-Production", lateSteps: 204, completedSteps: 618, openSteps: 1162},
        {Batch: 1245, Contact: "MFG-QC", lateSteps: 293, completedSteps: 1046, openSteps: 1917},
        {Batch: 4123, Contact: "MFG-WTE", lateSteps: 619, completedSteps: 1874, openSteps: 3425},
        {Batch: 5123, Contact: "PKG-MQA", lateSteps: 536, completedSteps: 1847, openSteps: 3397},
        {Batch: 6123, Contact: "PKG-Production", lateSteps: 281, completedSteps: 866, openSteps: 1543},
        {Batch: 7123, Contact: "PKG-QA Floor", lateSteps: 113, completedSteps: 52, openSteps: 580},
        {Batch: 8123, Contact: "PKG-QP", lateSteps: 74, completedSteps: 234, openSteps: 399},
        {Batch: 9123, Contact: "MFG-QC", lateSteps: 293, completedSteps: 1046, openSteps: 1917},
        {Batch: 723, Contact: "MFG-WTE", lateSteps: 619, completedSteps: 1874, openSteps: 3425},
        {Batch: 2343, Contact: "PKG-MQA", lateSteps: 536, completedSteps: 1847, openSteps: 3397},
        ];
```

So here as per Legends

> totalSteps = openSteps+completedSteps;
>
> completedSteps = sum of all completedSteps of Same Contact
>
> lateSteps = sum of all lateSteps of Same Contact

By using this want to create multiple pie charts depending on the Contact mentioned and do sum of all respective values.

Comment: The data you show is already aggregated, so it is unlikely that dc.js and crossfilter will be able to filter and re-aggregate the data for you. You want to think what are the individual items you want selected and summed over. Looks like they might be the steps? These should be the rows of the array you pass to crossfilter. Then create a dimension and group for each of the pie charts which bins and sums the rows to produce the measures you want to see in the pie charts.

Comment: BTW if `totalSteps` includes `lateSteps` and `completedSteps` then you have pie charts which add up to more than 100%, which could be misleading. It may be better to have `otherSteps` rather than `totalSteps`

Comment: Hi @Gordon I modified the data array basically I want contact wise pieChart if Contact repeates then add its open,complted and late count.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. Not sure what you mean in your comment, but from your edits it sounds like you are displaying the same data twice - it's [definitely not a good idea](https://www.nbcchicago.com/news/local/FOX-News-Chart-Fails-Math-73711092.html) to have pie charts that add up to more than 100%.

Comment: But that's not my main concern - my main concern is that you have already aggregated your data, so there really isn't any way to filter and aggregate it using crossfilter. Please consider looking at the original data set and considering how that could be filtered and aggregated.